# Possible to use pipe formatter of Angular inside textbox control while editing?

Tags: html, angular, input, format

I've declared a format for splitting large numbers in groups of three digits and use it frequently like this.

```
<div>Huge number: {{ i_am_huge | make_threesome }}</div>
```

Now, there's a request for corresponding functionality but implemented in an input control like this one.

```
<input id="numeroUno"
       type="text">
```

The approach I can think of is to listen to typing and for each key perform a reformatting of the contents of the box like so.

```
<input id="numeroUno"
       type="text"
       (keyup)="formatify">
```

However, while this approach would work, I can't stop wondering if it's too much of Q&D, so before I build a whole control fauna around this paradigm, I'd like to get more info.

The usual googling didn't give me much. However, give a rather unusual nature of the requirement, it might be hard to find.

The assumption at this point is that input control isn't supposed to be used that way, which explains the clunkyness of my approach.

Comment: Is your intent just to format your number like `1,000,123,456.99`?

Comment: @LeaReimann Yes, except for the separator character. It's supposed to be a space. Also, only integers are needed. No "cents". Why do you ask? Is there a special case smooth solution for just that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Directive. In [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-71meib?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.pipe.ts) you can see how work.

The directive store in the variable "value" the string without spaces. Each a change happens (I use @HotListener(input)) get the position of the cursor, get the value of the element, remove spaces, formate the number and put the cursor in the position

```
@Directive({ selector: "[testPipe]" })
export class TestPipe  implements OnInit {

  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  private value: any;
  constructor(@Optional() private ngControl:NgControl,
                private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }
  @HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
  onInput() {
    let pos = this.el.selectionStart; //get the position of the cursor
    this.value = this.el.value.replace(/ /gi, ""); //store the value without spaces
    if (this.value.length%3==1) //If we must add an extra space
      pos++;
    //Yes, it's a "bizarro" way to separate in group of three 
    this.el.value=this.value.match(/(.+?)(?=(.{3})+(?!.)|$)/g).join(' ');
    //this.el.value=this.value.match(/(\d+?)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)|$)/g).join(' ');
    //Finally give the position of cursor
    this.el.selectionStart = this.el.selectionEnd = pos;
    if (this.ngControl)
        this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.el.value,{emit:false})

  }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.value = this.el.value.replace(/ /gi, "");
    this.el.value=this.value.match(/(.+?)(?=(.{3})+(?!.)|$)/g).join(' ');
//  this.el.value=this.value.match(/(\d+?)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)|$)/g).join(' ');
    if (this.ngControl)
        this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.el.value,{emit:false})

  }
}
```

**Update** I add a @Optional() ngControl:NgControl in constructor, so, if the directive is applied to a ngControl (the input belong to a formGroup or has a [(ngModel)], change the value too

Comment: Awesome answer. Two more things, though. Firstly, I believe there's a bug in the code because when I backspace, I can only delete the digits and when I get to a space, further removal doesn't take place. Secondly, I didn't get the part with *ngControl*. Would you be willing to elaborate and perhaps illuminate with an example for each of the two cases (application to *ngControl* vs non-control).

Comment: About the ngControl: if you use a input like `<input testPipe [(ngModel)]="variable">{{variable}}` or using ReactiveForm `<input formControlName="name1" testPipe >{{myForm?.value.name1}}` and not use setValue, the variable not get the same value you see. .If you inject in the constructor NgControl and try to applied the directive to a normal input `<input testPipe>`, Angular give you an error becaouse this input is not a "NgControl" -this is the reason becaouse we use @Optional(). About the backspace, you're correct, I need think about it. (I've updated the stackblitz to show ngControl)

Comment: About backspace, I imagine that a backspace in a "space" make the same that a left arrow. I use a variable oldValue to check this.

Comment: The implementation of the *ngOnInit* is there for a reason, right? What is the reason exactly?

Comment: If at first, you feed the control with a number like "123456" and not put the ngOnInit, the value is not formatted

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you should rather use an [(attribute) directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) here. You can use directives for validation purposes, so why not use it to do formatting in your input fields (actually trying to do something like this in my own project at the moment).

Basically it would somewhat look like that (example from the angular docs):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input('appHighlight') highlightColor: string;

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight(this.highlightColor || 'red');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  }

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

This way you can manipulate the values inside of the input field and listen on events like `click`.

Another thing you have to do before it works: Add the directive (very similar to `[ngStyle]` or `[ngClass]`) to your input filed via `[your-directives-name]`. Look at the following code snippet and how it's done:

```
<h1>My First Attribute Directive</h1>

<h4>Pick a highlight color</h4>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='lightgreen'">Green
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='yellow'">Yellow
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='cyan'">Cyan
</div>
<p [appHighlight]="color">Highlight me!</p>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm doing something like that already but as a part of the whole component and not on the encapsulated level So it's definitely a good suggestions for improvement. A follow-up to that. If I pass in *donkey* I will get the donkeyest color of the background. But the computer might not know of the color of donkeys. Wouldn't it make more sense to send in RGB code and validate it with a regex? Also, I see that you go into *nativeElement* - isn't it a bit clunky to horse around like that instead of "real" Angular code (whatever that might be, hehe)?

Comment: `ElementRef` and `NativeElement` are part of the "real" Angular code. Sure, you don't need to do it like that, but if you want to manipulate anything in the template you probably can't do it without these two.

Comment: Came to think about the syntax. Why would we need the brackets in the code when setting the directive in the HTML markup? I'd find it more natural to go *<div myDir>xxx</div>*.

Comment: Brackets around a directive are completely optional here. You just have to know the difference when [binding values](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property) to an `@Input` property. Choose wisely :)