# Reactive forms Angular format input data

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

Hi I am new to Angular Reactive forms and have been working on trying to figure this out.

What I want to do is format the input data to uppercase:/

```
<input #stateInput matInput type="text" 
formControlName="state" 
[matAutocomplete]="autoState" maxlength="2"
(keyup)="stateInput.value.toUpperCase()" 
required>
```

I haven't been able to get this to work?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I like use `<input style="text-transform:uppercase">` and in submit trasnform the variable. Another way you must take account if you type in middle of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just simple use below code which will convert input to UpperCase instantly ,

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
```

here is an example [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkpxsv)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result , use below option

**Issue:** After changing input value to uppercase, it has to be reassigned to show in Input field

```html
<input
    type="text"
    [formControl]="state"
    #stateInput
    (keyup)="stateInput.value = stateInput.value.toUpperCase()"
  />
```

code sandbox for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/6l9nk4k2zn

Comment: the problem with your code is when you try to keyup in middle of the input

Comment: @Eliseo, that scenario is not possible as per SO question , as maxlength is only two

Comment: ::glups:: I dont see this detail

Comment: @Eliseo, i just tried to keyup in the middle of input , it works as expected - https://codesandbox.io/s/0pwrknw97l  .. This works in that scenario because I am changing complete input value to uppercase not based on location :)

Comment: when I type "abde", and I put the cursor between b and d and type c (to form "abcde", the cursor goes to the end of the input. Therefore, if you write in the html {{state.value}}, you can see that the value is not to upper. If you put maxlength="2" and type ab, go yo the first, remove the "a" and type C, the cursor goes to the end too

Comment: ... If you want to control the position of cursor, you need "play" with "selectionStart and selectionEnd of the html element, some like a "complex" directive in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55086460/possible-to-use-pipe-formatter-of-angular-inside-textbox-control-while-editing/55087249#55087249. To convert to upper I think it's too much code